# Detecting proximity of multiple objects and changing their material color

Tags: c#, list, unity-game-engine, distance, collision

I have a problem with the correct detection of object proximities using distance calculations and hope one of you can help me.

**What i want:**
There are several instantiated game objects with the same tag in my scene and I want to change their material color if their distance on the x and z axis is below "1". For this I iterate over a list of all objects and compare their position with the position of the current game object.

**The problem:**
Material colors are changing randomly on colliding objects and sometimes don't change back once the collision is over.

**My code so far:**

```
     public class DistanceTester : MonoBehaviour
 {
     void Start()
     {
 
     }
 
     void Update()
     {
         var menschen = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Mensch");
         float positionX = transform.position.x;
         float positionZ = transform.position.z;
 
         foreach (GameObject mensch in menschen)
         {
             float distanceX = Mathf.Abs(mensch.transform.position.x - positionX);
             float distanceZ = Mathf.Abs(mensch.transform.position.z - positionZ);
 
             if (gameObject != mensch) //Making sure the object is not the same
             {
                 if (distanceX <= 1 && distanceZ <= 1)
                 {
                     GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = Color.red;
                     mensch.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = Color.red;
                 }
                 else
                 {
                     GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = Color.green;
                     mensch.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = Color.green;
                 }
             }
         }
     }
 }
```

I already tried to use triggers for collision detection but would like to use a more efficient way like in my example above.

Comment: You know btw there is [`Vector3.Distance`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Distance.html) ;) Also .. why would your way be more efficient than using colliders? You are using `FindGameObjectsWithTag` and iterate each and every of these objects and set colors using `GetComponent` ... doesn't sound very efficient to me tbh ;)

Comment: Yes I know and I already had it implemented but got the same result. I also don't need the value of Y so I thought it would be more efficient to not use a Vector3.

Comment: Could you please point out a way on how I could detect the collisions more efficiently than iterating over all the objects? I already had a setup with colliders but it didn't work well with fast moving objects.

Comment: The fastest way I know is iterating with [OverlapSphere](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.OverlapSphere.html) (if you have 3D colliders on your objects) and [OverlapCircel](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics2D.OverlapCircle.html) in 2D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main issue is probbaly that you also set

```
GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = ...;
```

so what if you are close to `menschen[0]` but far away from `menschen[1]` ?

**→ You reset your color always with the result of the last item in `menschen`!**

---

It sounds like you should rather only handle your own object since all of the other objects do the same thing right?

```
using Sytsem.Linq;

public class DistanceTester : MonoBehaviour
{
     // reference this via the Inspector already
     [SerializeField] private Renderer _renderer;

     private void Awake()
     {
         // As fallback get it ONCE
         if(!_renderer) _renderer = GetComponent<Renderer>();
     }
 
     private void Update()
     {
         // If possible you should also store this ONCE
         var menschen = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Mensch");

         // This checks if ANY of the objects that is not this object is clsoe enough
         if(menschen.Where(m => m != gameObject).Any(m => (transform.position - m.transform.position).sqrMagnitude < 1))
         {
             _renderer.material.color = Color.red;
         }
         else
         {
             _renderer.material.color = Color.green;
         } 
     }
 }
```

Where this Linq expression using [`Where`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.where) and [`Any`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.any)

```
menschen.Where(m => m!= gameObject).Any(m => (transform.position - m.transform.position).sqrMagnitude < 1)
```

Basically equals doing something like

```
var isClose = false;
foreach(var m in menschen)
{
    if(m == gameObject) continue;

    if((transform.position - m.transform.position).sqrMagnitude < 1)
    {
        isClose = true;
        break;
    }
}

if(isClose)
{
    ...
```

---

Note that it would still be more efficient if you can store the result of `FindGameObjectsWithTag` **once** instead of obtaining it every frame.

Assuming that any of your `Mensch` objects will have the component `DistanceTester` you could even implement some sort of "auto-detection" by using a pattern like

```
public class DistanceTester : MonoBehaviour
{
    private static HashSet<DistanceTester> _instances = new HashSet<DistanceTester>();

    private void Awake()
    {
        _instances.Add(this);

        ...
    }

    private void OnDestroy()
    {
        _instances.Remove(this);
    }

    ...
}
```

Then you could quite efficient iterate through the `_instances` instead.

Even more efficient though would actually be to iterate only once from a global controller instead of doing that in each and every instance of `DistanceTester`!

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot for pointing me in the right direction. Your code is way smoother than mine. I need to call FindGameObjectsWithTag every frame since the objects are getting generated/destroyed dynamically. How would you set up the iteration from a global controller? Would I need to nest another foreach loop inside the first one to be able to compare the objects or is there a better way with Linq?